# Issues with jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Having a few issues with a jquery slider that I'm trying to make.

On jsf: [`jsfiddle.net/0hq91y5v/`](http://jsfiddle.net/0hq91y5v/)

I've got five dot li links that I'm trying to link to each slide. I obviously want to make it so that clicking on each button changes the class to activeDot and removes the class from the current active button. I've tried this in jquery but it's not working.

I've also added some code to try and fade between the different slides after clicking on each button using the same method, by switching the activeSlide class for each, but this also won't work.

Lastly, looking at the code I've used, what would be a better / more semantic method of adding and removing the activeSlide class upon clicking on the associated button, rather than doing like I have and creating a function for each button?

Comment: would you mind to use http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ ?

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your current jQuery Code and markup too.

take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hq91y5v/5/)

this code will help you to achieve the behaviour you are expecting, you can add fadeIn() and fadeOut() as you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var activeSlide = $('#homeSlider > .activeSlide');
    var activeDot = $('#homeSliderNav > ul > li.activeDot');

    $('#homeSliderNav > ul > li').click(function() {
        $('#homeSliderNav > ul > li').removeClass('activeDot');
        $(this).addClass('activeDot');
        $('.slide').removeClass('activeSlide');
        var slide = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        $('#' + slide).addClass('activeSlide');

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I've tried adding your code to my site but I've switched the id's to classes so I don't have the id used twice (for the slide and the button), but I can't get this to work. In jsf: jsfiddle.net/0hq91y5v/1/.

Comment: you can not use single id twice in markup, it's a thumb rule. Checkout http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp Definition and Usage section. As I already mentioned in description that you need to make some changes in markup too.

Comment: No, what I meant was you've used id twice in your jsfiddle. You've applied id="homeSlideOne" to both the slide itself and the button for it. I then tried to change id to class for each of these and now the slider doesn't work. Check out the jsfiddle link I just posted

Comment: Well, Sorry for that, I've updated it. Unfortunately I'm not able to see any piece of code which I've provided you in different fiddle.

here is updated one : http://jsfiddle.net/0hq91y5v/5/

Comment: Thanks. Working fine now

Comment: @Nick my pleasure :)